# Apache POI and SUBTOTAL formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, worksheet-function

```
=SUMPRODUCT((K:K="yes")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(K10,ROW(K:K)-MIN(ROW(K10:K10)),0))))
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT((K:K="yes")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(K10,ROW(K:K)-MIN(ROW(K10:K10)),0))))+(NOW()*0)
```

This is the excel formula that is used in one of the sheets in the generated xls workbook using java **poi** api.
It evaluates correctly only if I press Enter on the cell in Excel.
Formula evaluator and `wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)` doesn't seem to work.

The java code is :

```
cell.setCellFormula("SUMPRODUCT((K:K=\"yes\")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(K10,ROW(K:K)-MIN(ROW(K10:K10)),0))))");
```

The goal of the formula is to count the occurence of "yes" in column K but only for visible rows after filtering. K10 is the cell from where the actual data starts. Rows above this cell contain headers.

Comment: I don't believe there is an answer possible without having [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including a sample of data this complex formula works with. But at least you should show the code lines which put the formula in a cell using `apache poi`. And you should telling more special what "doesn't seem to work" means. What does the cell show before pressing `Enter` in `Excel`?

Comment: Java code which is adding the formula in excel is : 
 cell.setCellFormula("SUMPRODUCT((K:K="yes")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(K10,ROW(K:K)-MIN(ROW(K10:K10)),0))))");                                The value it shows before pressing Enter is 0.

Comment: Please edit your question and show all relevant informations there. Btw: `cell.setCellFormula("SUMPRODUCT((K:K="yes")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(K10,ROW(K:K)-MIN(ROW(K10:K10)),0))))");` will not compile (unmasked quotes in string literal). And please also tell what data is in column `K`. The goal of the formula is to count the occurence of "yes" in column `K` but only for visible rows, is it? But what is the goal of the `K10`? And what else data is in column `K` beside of "yes"?

Comment: I have updated the question. column  'K'  contains yes or no values

Comment: I can confirm this to be a problem using `HSSF`. But it  has nothing to do with formula recalculation. `OFFSET` itself is volatile as well as `NOW`. Both force formula recalculation even without setting `setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)`. But in the binary `*.xls` file the `ROW(K:K)` in `OFFSET` does not initially evaluating as array. So it is always `1` instead of `{1,2,3,4,5,...}`. Not clear why that is. Using `XSSF` (`*.xlsx`) it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this to be a problem using `HSSF`. But it has nothing to do with formula recalculation. `OFFSET` itself is volatile as well as `NOW`. Both force formula recalculation even without setting `setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)`. But in the binary `*.xls` file the `ROW(K:K)` in `OFFSET` does not initially evaluating as array. So it is only once evaluated to `1` (`ROW(K1)`) instead to the array `{1,2,3,4,5,...}` (`ROW(K1), ROW(K2), ROW(K3), ...`).  Using `XSSF` (`*.xlsx`) it works.

I found the problem is how `apache poi` creates the `HSSF` formula for `SUMPRODUCT`. `SUMPRODUCT` always is an array function. So all functions embedded in `SUMPRODUCT` also should be array functions. But `apache poi` does not set the `CLASS_ARRAY` to the functions which are embedded in `SUMPRODUCT`. Instead it sets `CLASS_VALUE` as if the functions were stand alone.

The following working draft shows this problem. There is a method `makeArrayFormula` which changes all `FuncVarPtg` (function variable parse things) which were `CLASS_VALUE` to `CLASS_ARRAY`. After running that method, the `SUMPRODUCT` formula works as expected also in `HSSF`.

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.CellValueRecordInterface;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.FormulaRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.FormulaRecordAggregate;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.Ptg;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.FuncVarPtg;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class CreateExcelFormula {

 static void makeArrayFormula(HSSFCell formulaCell) throws Exception {
  Field _record = HSSFCell.class.getDeclaredField("_record");
  _record.setAccessible(true); 
  CellValueRecordInterface recordInterface = (CellValueRecordInterface)_record.get(formulaCell);
  System.out.println(recordInterface);
  if (recordInterface instanceof FormulaRecordAggregate) {
   FormulaRecordAggregate formulaRecordAggregate = (FormulaRecordAggregate)recordInterface;
   FormulaRecord formulaRecord = formulaRecordAggregate.getFormulaRecord();
   Ptg[] ptgs = formulaRecord.getParsedExpression();
   for (Ptg ptg : ptgs) {
    if (ptg instanceof FuncVarPtg) {
     if (ptg.getPtgClass() == Ptg.CLASS_VALUE) {
      ptg.setClass(Ptg.CLASS_ARRAY);
     }
    }
   }
   formulaRecord.setParsedExpression(ptgs);
  }
  System.out.println(recordInterface);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
       Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls") ) {
       //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Row row;
   Cell cell;

   row = sheet.createRow(0);

   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("F:");
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   //cell.setCellFormula("SUMPRODUCT((K:K=\"yes\")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(K10,ROW(K:K)-MIN(ROW(K10:K10)),0))))");
   cell.setCellFormula("SUMPRODUCT((K10:K10000=\"yes\")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(K10,ROW(K10:K10000)-ROW(K10),0))))");
   if (cell instanceof HSSFCell) {
    makeArrayFormula((HSSFCell)cell);
   }

   for (int r = 9; r < 30; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r);
    cell = row.createCell(10);
    if (r % 2 == 0) cell.setCellValue("yes"); else cell.setCellValue("no");
   }

   for (int r = 14; r < 19; r++) {
    sheet.getRow(r).setZeroHeight(true);
   }  

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Btw.: One should never using full column references like `K:K` in  array formulas. This is a performance night mare. And the `MIN` around `ROW(K10:K10)` is superfluous.

Comment: It worked like a charm. All your points noted. Thank you for your time.